# Browser doesn't stay signed into Google when logged in using GMail app confirmation

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

I have a case where I have a forgotten the password to my main Google account. I can signin by following these steps:

1. Type in username.
2. Click "Forgot password?".
3. Switch to the GMail app for iPhone and confirm that I am indeed the person trying to login to my account.
4. Switch back to browser.
5. When presented with the options of "Update password" and "Continue", I click "Continue".

I am doing this on an iPhone, and I have done this in both Safari and Brave. In either browser, when I close it and re-open it, I am logged out. But, if I log into a Google account that I know the password to by entering the password to it, then I do not get logged out of it by closing and reopening my browser. Why is this? How do I get my confirnation-based login to stay logged in with Google?

(Note: The reason why I'm not just resetting my account's password is outside the scope of this question, so don't bother asking why I'm not doing that because I'm not going to answer.)

Comment: Are you blocking your third Party coookies or in anyotherway resptricting access to your logged in Data

Answer (score 0):

Read [System requirements and browsers](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375082?hl=en) from the Google Accounts Help Center.

It lists the supported web browsers and asks users to make sure to enable cookies and JavaScript.

Note: Safari and Brave are not mentioned. I use Safari with Gmail daily, and I have no problems staying signed in even after restarting my computers. I have used Brave, too, with no issues either.